# Was no community moderator election conducted in 2015?

Tags: discussion

I came across this dedicated [Community Moderator Elections](https://english.stackexchange.com/election) page on EL&U.

I can't help but wonder...

- Did the EL&U elections happen in 2015? If not, why?
- At what intervals (once in 2 years/ 3 years) are the EL&U moderator elections held? ( I observed that the elections were conducted in 2011,2012 and 2014 in EL&U. However, I don't see any election details for the year 2013. So it is not regular is my inference )
- What factors necessitate moderator elections on EL&U? (spurt in low-quality questions, spike in number of users would be my guesses)

I see a "SIMILAR QUESTION" populated in the right panel as I type this - [Will there be a 2014 Community Moderator election?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/will-there-be-a-2014-community-moderator-election) posted by **Mari-LouA**. I'd like to re-ask the same for this year.

- Will there be a 2016 Community Moderator election?

I found [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) from 2010 by Jeff Atwood. I doubt whether it is relevant after 6 years.  I assumed that community moderator elections are conducted every year across all the 150+ sites in SE network.

Comment: I am lost in the negations here. Will the downvoters of this post please explain whether their downvotes mean that they agree, or disagree, that there was _no_ community moderator election in 2015, or disagree with a perceived general sentiment of this post, or whatever else?

Comment: They aren't held regularly, as far as I know; only if the people in charge determine that more moderators are needed.

Comment: Related (possible dupe):[What are the criteria for being able to vote in a moderator election?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7327/8019).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No, there was no election in 2015, because it wasn't needed (see 3 below).
2. Elections are held as needed (see 3 below), so there is no set interval.
3. Elections are held when the amount of moderator intervention required exceeds the amount of intervention possible from the existing team. That is, when more manpower is needed, the community is asked whether they can provide it and to volunteer if so moved.
4. It's impossible to say what will happen in 2016 (see 3 above). It is definitely not possible to say how many vacancies there may be to fill, other than to say it may be zero and is more-or-less certain to be less than ten.

Jeff's post is still relevant, although not really relevant to your question. It covers the necessity for self-government and the mechanism of the elections themselves.