# If I am NOT running for Mod, but would like to state my personal platform

Tags: discussion, support

Recently, Meta has become a little confusing for me...

We have Mod elections, and Question collection, but if I am not actively seeking election yet  would still like to post my opinion vis a vis site policy, where do I post my platform?

Edit

I have certain opinions about the site going forward into the future.

Do I do it on the elections site?

I think comments section is not helpful.

---

I have been reviewing the comments, but can some user please explain how I can post a candidacy type of post without actually running?

---

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by stating or posting a platform? I would expect the posting or stating of an opinion? For that, I would say Meta is a good place?

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica We have election. We have candidates. We also have 20K+users here who would like regime change, yet are unwilling to run. I am asking how do we campaign for issues here apart from voting candidates who have posted their candidacy.

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand. So you were thinking of posting a link to a campaign site of sorts? Wouldn't it be more convenient to just put up a Meta post with your opinion on those issues? (By the way, for me the most important issue would be the unfriendly/critical comments that are posted often and everywhere, especially to new users.)

Comment: The new policy could have been established at the beginning of the election process. Either by posting a question before the nomination phase or in comments beneath those self nominated. It's "too late" now to hear their stance on anything unless you visit chat. You can ask your questions to the candidates there. If you're looking for a revolution, we'd all love to change the world but it ain't gonna happen any time soon.

Comment: I'm saying your opportunity to get candidates to state their position on issues that matter to you can still be asked if you visit chat. As users we're obliged to follow Stack Exchange guidelines and regulations. If you're a mod, IMO, you stand a greater chance of making your voice heard in what is called the Teachers' lounge. But be careful, the last time there was a debate about CoC and policy, a highly respected six-diamond moderator was "fired".

Comment: So post your ideas on Meta, but there's a risk they will probably get closed for being opinion-based....unless they generate a lot of *constructive* debate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA A number of us have been treated badly here recently, and after my experiment with reddit, I can see parallels///WHO was fired?

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine does the username Reinstate Monica ring a bell? Before the war, before Covid but about two years after Trump's election. You were around, surely? https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13498/support-for-monica-cellio

Comment: @Mari-LouA Of course I remember. I think we need to be more inclusionary (if that is a word) I was gonna include that in my policies...but TXS...I think there are too many "old guys" who are "overlording" the site. We need fresh ideas...

Comment: We need *good* *interesting* questions too.

Comment: Your idea of having non-candidates posting their own answers to the election questions is novel. It's not the intentions of those questions and is probably secondary, but is still interesting. I think the most obvious solution though was to post your own candidate questions (in case others didn't cover it) or post your own answer as a comment. Otherwise we might have to post a new meta question to track non-candidate answers. Note that Meta questions can be much more opinion seeking than Main.

Comment: Oh... I don't think you -can- do it on the elections site. Anyway I think there'd be more solutions if this happened before or earlier in the first stage of the election process.

Comment: @Mitch Thank you...from time to time I leave the site, especially when it becomes contentious. As far as I can see, I was never notified by email, which should be the primary means of notification, not searching through meta posts. BTW, When I mean contentious, you need only do an @ search on this thread...present company excluded...:-)

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine You don't need to wade through meta posts. I got a notification (in the SE inbox, upper right) when the election started. Sure, you have to visit the website (ie it's not an email), but that ensures that you're minimally active to participate. As to contentious, I find in this very particular thread (or this Meta question) people have only been very helpful.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine by 'this thread' I take that to refer to this very sequence of comments on your meta question (but also Laurel's answer). All very helpful and not contentious.

Comment: @Mitch I'm sorry I have to spell this out...Mary-Lou came off quite aggressive  in a *previous   post on meta**, and I decided to delete the whole damn thing. I expect comments to be helpful, but unkind remarks and less than helpful suggestions really turn me off. She has already told me in other comments that she has been banned in the past on meta (hence cannot run for Mod) , and I now can see why.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine Just so you're more aware of where I am coming from, I'm only referring to things I can see here now because that's all I am aware of. .

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine quote one comment of mine when I was aggressive towards you. I can be critical, I can be blunt and I can be direct and say what I think. However, if you view them as being rude and aggressive you can flag my comment(s) and ask for them to be deleted. P.S I lack the diplomatic gene in my DNA makeup but in the long run, I think am generally a positive person in this community.

Comment: Here is a question that I posted on Meta Stack Exchange which is somewhat related to your recent posts here on meta: [How many users eligible to vote were active in the three months preceding an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377492/how-many-users-eligible-to-vote-were-active-in-the-three-months-preceding-an-ele)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I deleted the other post because it was beginning to sound contentious, and in those cases I usually prefer to disengage....plz don't pursue this. I have enormous respect for you, but this has gone too far for me. Even If you cannot understand how I feel, that does not make my sentiments less valid. –

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine Downvotes in Meta mean "I disagree", either with the proposal or the premise of the question. The tooltip about "no research" is for Main, not Meta, and is not very helpful!

Comment: Why would you not Post those views here, as Questions? How would that not suit you?

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet is to post a new question on meta advocating for the changes you want to see on the site. Maybe a few questions depending on how much you have to say, since it works best when each question is about a single topic.

The election channels are intended as a way to figure out what people you want to moderate the site, so it's not great for other types of discussions. People won't be looking at anything related to the election  once it's over anyway. Plus, it's actually impossible to continue the discussion in some cases: no more nominations (or even comments on nominations) can be posted now that voting on candidates has started.

I realize that Meta isn't the best place for all discussions. Would anyone want to see a chat room dedicated to moderation? It would be a place for people to bring attention to posts that they think need attention, namely close, reopen, delete or undelete votes. (I know Stack Overflow has this type of chat room, and I think some smaller sites do too.)

Comment: I know of at least one chat room focusing on community moderation issues in the past. And I've overseen a chat room called Sandy Lines for discussions about policies back when I was spending unhealthy amounts of time on EL&U. Feel free to open such a room. The mods might even feature it to give it more publicity. It can take some effort to look after the room, but if you're personally interested in the topic, it can be worth doing.

Comment: I just would like to say that for ASD people, chatroom can be problematic...and may exclude some users.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine I understand. You still have meta, and you might get some benefit from viewing chat incognito if that works for you. (The benefit of chat over meta is that it's easier to ask about a lot of unrelated posts within a short timeframe.)

Comment: txs..I will take that under consideration